# Getting 401 unauthorized error on first load

Tags: angular, authorization, token, http-status-code-401

When I am loading my application for 1st time it gives me 401 exception.
Below is the code

Interceptor.service.ts

```
public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let retries = 0;
    let clonedRequest = request.clone();

    // skip http interceptor if skip is included in header of request
    if (request.headers.get('skip')) return next.handle(request);

    // attach token to the header
    clonedRequest = this.addToken(request, this.tokenService.getJwtToken());

    return next.handle(clonedRequest).pipe(
      catchError((error, restart) => {
        this.httpError =error;
         if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === this.HTTP_AUTHORIZATION_ERROR && retries === 0) {
          retries++;

          // refresh, pull new token, AND make the request again if request returns 401
          return  concat( this.handle401Error(request, next), restart);
        }

        // send user to login page if refresh did not work
        if (retries > 1) {
          this.tokenService.login();
       }
       return throwError(() => error);
      }),
      finalize(() => {
         this.handleErrors(this.httpError);
        })
    );
  }
  public handleErrors(error:any){
    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
    localStorage.removeItem('errordetails');
    localStorage.setItem('errordetails', JSON.stringify(error));
    this.router.navigate(['/error']) .then(() => {
      this.windowReload();
    });
   }
  }

  private addToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: any) {

    let clonedRequestWithToken = request.clone();
    clonedRequestWithToken = clonedRequestWithToken.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } });

    return clonedRequestWithToken;
  }

  windowReload() {
        window.location.reload();
       }

  public handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    if (!this.isRefreshing) {
      this.isRefreshing = true;
      this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);

      return this.tokenService.fetchNewAccessToken().pipe(
        switchMap((tokens: any[]) => {
          this.isRefreshing = false;
          const token = transformToken(tokens[0]);
          this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token.accessToken);
          if (!!tokens[0]) {
            let accessToken;
            accessToken = tokens[0];
            localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(accessToken));
          }
          return next.handle(this.addToken(request, token.accessToken));
        })
      );
    }

    return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
      filter(token => token !== null),
      take(1),
      switchMap(jwt => {
        return next.handle(this.addToken(request, jwt));
      })
   );
  }
}
```

Token.service.ts

```
public fetchNewAccessToken() {
    const tokenUrl = `${environment.localTokenUrl || '.'}`;

    return this.http
      .get<any>(`${tokenUrl}/.auth/refresh`, { headers: { skip: 'true' }, withCredentials: true, responseType: 'json' })
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(() =>
          this.http
            .get(`${tokenUrl}/.auth/me`, { headers: { skip: 'true' }, withCredentials: true, responseType: 'json' })
            .pipe(
              tap((tokens: any) => {
                if (!tokens || !tokens.length) return;
                const token = transformToken(tokens[0]);
              return this.store.dispatch(loadTokenSuccess(token));
              })
            )
        ),
        catchError((error) => {          
          //  if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
            
          //   }
          //   else {
         this.login();
        //  }
         return of();
       })

      );
  }

  public login() {
    const tokenUrl =`${environment.localTokenUrl || '.'}`;
    window.location.href = `${tokenUrl}/.auth/login/aad/callback`;
  }

  public getJwtToken() {
    const accessToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')!);
    return accessToken[0].access_token;
  }
```

It is throwing 401 exceptions on first load if I try to reload the page again it loads successfully.The application should load properly on first load .Also if i click any link to redirect to other page it throws 401 exception. Please suggest